# adjust axes Highcharts plotted versus

Tags: graph, highcharts, scale

You will see'm using Highcharts suite to create graphics on my website. The problem is that to make a graph vs, that is, a y-axis on each side of the graph, the scale of these is not equal. The 0 does not match, there is some way to control this?

What I get is that both y-axes coincide in their scale to make checks at a glance, without relying on the scale that makes Highcharts

Greetings and thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set the [`yAxis.min`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.min) and [`yAxis.max`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.max) values that you need.

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 200
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two or more yAxis, set [alignTicks](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks) as false.